Bash Flags are not passing through
For some reason, my flags are not being passed through. I'm using the unix getopts function,
Where I am going wrong?
#!/bin/bash
### Pass Flags
#Define the help function
function help(){
    echo "Options:";
    echo "-rg    Resource Group Name"
    echo "-loc    Location of Resource Group"
    echo "-clus    Cluster Name"
    echo "-e    Email for LetsEncrypt"
    echo "-hos    Hostname for Nginx"
    exit 1;
}


#Initialize the default values for the variables.
rg="rg";
loc="location";
clus="cluster";
e="email";
hos="hostname";

#Define the getopts variables
options="rg:loc:clus:e:hos:h";

#Start the getopts code
while getopts $options opt; do
    case $opt in
            rg) #Get the username
                    rg=$OPTARG
            ;;
            loc) #Get the password
                    location=$OPTARG
            ;;
            clus) #Get the repository name
                    cluster=$OPTARG
            ;;
            e) #Get the service name
                    email=$OPTARG
            ;;
            hos) #Get the branch name
                    hostname=$OPTARG
            ;;
            h) #Execute the help function
        "echo here"
                    help;
            ;;
            \?) #unrecognized option - show help
                    echo "Invalid option."
                    help;
            ;;
    esac
done

#This tells getopts to move on to the next argument.
shift $((OPTIND-1))
#End getopts code


#rg="jc-test29-aks-rg"
#location="francecentral"
#cluster="jc-aks-test29-cluster"

## Create RG
echo "Creating Resource Group $rg"
az group create --name $rg --location $location

## Create AKS Cluster
echo "Creating AKS Cluster $cluster"

az aks create -g $rg -n $cluster --enable-managed-identity --node-vm-size Standard_B2s --node-count 3 --load-balancer-sku Standard

## Conect to Cluster
echo "Connecting to AKS Cluster"
az aks get-credentials --resource-group $rg --name $cluster --overwrite-existing

## Wait for the Cluster to Come online.
sleep 5m

## Add the Repos
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm repo add cert-manager https://charts.jetstack.io
helm repo add argo https://argoproj.github.io/argo-helm

## Install nginx-ingress
helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
--namespace ingress-nginx --create-namespace \
--set controller.replicaCount=2 \
--set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
--set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path"=/healthz \
--set controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy=Local \
--set controller.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
--set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux

## Install Cert Manager
helm install cert-manager cert-manager/cert-manager \
--namespace cert-manager --create-namespace \
--version v1.14.5 \
--set nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
--set installCRDs=true \
--set 'extraArgs={--dns01-recursive-nameservers=1.1.1.1:53}'

## Install ArgoCD 
helm install argocd argo/argo-cd \
--namespace argocd --create-namespace \
--version "6.9.2" \
--set installCRDs=true \
-f argocd-values.yaml \
-f deployenvcongifmap.yaml

cat << EOF | kubectl - 
port-forward svc/argocd-server 8080:443 
EOF

#git clone https://github.com/cloudflare/origin-ca-issuer.git

cd origin-ca-issuer

kubectl apply -f deploy/crds

kubectl apply -f deploy/rbac

kubectl apply -f deploy/manifests


kubectl create secret generic jasons-api-key \
    -n cert-manager\
    --from-literal api-token='VALUE'

sleep 60

cat  << EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: lets-encrypt-jasons-cert
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  acme:
    email: $email
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      # Secret resource that will be used to store the account's private key.
      name: lets-encrypt-jasons-cert
    solvers:
    - dns01:
        cloudflare:
          email: $email
          apiTokenSecretRef:
            name: jasons-api-key
            key: api-token
      selector:
        dnsZones:
        - 'companydomain.com'
EOF

cat << EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-jasons-cert
spec:
  secretName: letsencrypt-jasons-cert
  issuerRef:
    name: lets-encrypt-jasons-cert
    kind: ClusterIssuer
  commonName: 'testing-jc2.companydomain.com'
  dnsNames:
  - 'testing-jc2.companydoamin.com'
EOF


cat << EOF | kubectl replace -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: server
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-server
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: argocd
  name: argocd-server
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-server
EOF

cat << EOF | kubectl apply -f - 
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: argocd-server-ingress
  namespace: argocd
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: lets-encrypt-jasons-cert
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: 'HTTPS'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: $hostname
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: argocd-server
                port:
                  name: https
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - $hostname
      secretName: argocdingress-cert
EOF

echo "Deployment Complete"


getopts does not work with options like -clus.  See https://kodekloud.com/blog/bash-getopts/

If a user requests a help message, it seems reasonable that it is not an error if one is provided, so exit 1 is not appropriate.  If the user makes an error, it is appropriate to give a succinct error message and not appropriate to give a full usage statement.  Only give a usage message in response to a request, and exit 0.

I got this working by changing my flags to single characters. Getops does not work with flags that a multi charactered.
#!/bin/bash
### Pass Flags
#Define the help function
function help(){
    echo "Options:";
    echo "-r    Resource Group Name"
    echo "-l    Location of Resource Group"
    echo "-c    Cluster Name"
    echo "-e   Email for LetsEncrypt"
    echo "-d   domainname for Nginx"
    exit 1;
}


#Initialize the default values for the variables.
r="rg";
l="location";
c="cluster";
e="email";
d="domainname";

#Define the getopts variables
options=":r:l:c:e:d:h";

#Start the getopts code
while getopts ${options} opt; do
    case $opt in
            r) #Get the resourcegroupname
                    rg=${OPTARG}
            ;;
            l) #Get the location
                  location=${OPTARG}
            ;;
            c) #Get the cluster name
                    cluster=${OPTARG}
            ;;
            e) #Get the email
                    email=${OPTARG}
            ;;
            d) #Get the domain name
                    domainname=${OPTARG}
            ;;
            h) #Execute the help function
        "echo here"
                    help;
            ;;
            \?) #unrecognized option - show help
                    echo "Invalid option."
                    help;
            ;;
    esac
done

#This tells getopts to move on to the next argument.
shift $((OPTIND-1))
#End getopts code


#rg="jc-test29-aks-rg"
#location="francecentral" 
#cluster="jc-aks-test29-cluster"

## Create RG
echo "Creating Resource Group $rg"
az group create --name $rg --location "$location"

## Create AKS Cluster
echo "Creating AKS Cluster $cluster"

az aks create -g $rg -n $cluster--enable-managed-identity --node-vm-size Standard_B2s --node-count 3 --load-balancer-sku Standard

## Conect to Cluster
echo "Connecting to AKS Cluster"
az aks get-credentials --resource-group $rg --name $cluster --overwrite-existing

## Wait for the Cluster to Come online.
sleep 5m

## Add the Repos
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm repo add cert-manager https://charts.jetstack.io
helm repo add argo https://argoproj.github.io/argo-helm

## Install nginx-ingress
helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
--namespace ingress-nginx --create-namespace \
--set controller.replicaCount=2 \
--set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
--set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path"=/healthz \
--set controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy=Local \
--set controller.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
--set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux

## Install Cert Manager
helm install cert-manager cert-manager/cert-manager \
--namespace cert-manager --create-namespace \
--version v1.14.5 \
--set nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
--set installCRDs=true \
--set 'extraArgs={--dns01-recursive-nameservers=1.1.1.1:53}'

## Install ArgoCD 
helm install argocd argo/argo-cd \
--namespace argocd --create-namespace \
--version "6.9.2" \
--set installCRDs=true \
-f argocd-values.yaml \
-f deployenvcongifmap.yaml

cat << EOF | kubectl - 
port-forward svc/argocd-server 8080:443 
EOF

#git clone https://github.com/cloudflare/origin-ca-issuer.git

cd origin-ca-issuer

kubectl apply -f deploy/crds

kubectl apply -f deploy/rbac

kubectl apply -f deploy/manifests


kubectl create secret generic jasons-api-key \
    -n cert-manager\
    --from-literal api-token='APIKEY'

sleep 60

cat  << EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: lets-encrypt-jasons-cert
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  acme:
    email: $email
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      # Secret resource that will be used to store the account's private key.
      name: lets-encrypt-jasons-cert
    solvers:
    - dns01:
        cloudflare:
          email: $email
          apiTokenSecretRef:
            name: jasons-api-key
            key: api-token
      selector:
        dnsZones:
        - 'companydomain.com'
EOF

cat << EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-jasons-cert
spec:
  secretName: letsencrypt-jasons-cert
  issuerRef:
    name: lets-encrypt-jasons-cert
    kind: ClusterIssuer
  commonName: 'testing-jc2.companydomain.com'
  dnsNames:
  - 'testing-jc2.companydomain.com'
EOF


cat << EOF | kubectl replace -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: server
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-server
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: argocd
  name: argocd-server
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-server
EOF

cat << EOF | kubectl apply -f - 
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: argocd-server-ingress
  namespace: argocd
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: lets-encrypt-jasons-cert
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: 'HTTPS'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: $domainname
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: argocd-server
                port:
                  name: https
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - $domainname
      secretName: argocdingress-cert
EOF

echo "Deployment Complete"


I find your wording confusing. getopts does work with options that are multi-charactered (i.e. long options). It just does not work with option clustering, i.e. putting several single letter options together.

That's exactly backward, @user1934428. POSIX-conforming getopts absolutely does work with option clustering.  Indeed, the problem was that getopts was interpreting the OP's attempt at long options as option clusters.  On the other hand, getopts does not necessarily work with GNU-style long options, which are not addressed by POSIX.  Perhaps you are mixing that up with GNU's similarly-named command getopt, but (when used correctly) that understands both clustering and (GNU-style) long options. I don't know any standard command that handles the OP's original long option style.

@JohnBollinger : Thanks for clarification. You are right of course.
